# What is the right approach to using recursive function in a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a nested comment system similar to reddit where comments be nested under another comment and have a practically unlimited level of depth.

The comment model uses a self referencing id.

I have a partial view called comment that renders a single comment and I am trying to use a recursive function to draw out each comment one by one.

view

```
<% comments.where(parent_id: nil).each do |parent| %>
  <!-- render root node -->
  <%= render partial: "comment", locals: { comment: parent } %>
  <!-- recursively render child nodes -->
  <%= render_children(parent.id) %>
<% end %>
```

helper

```
def render_children(id)
  Comment.where(parent_id: id).each do |comment|
    render partial: "comment", locals: { comment: comment }
    render_children(comment.id)
  end 
end
```

This doesn't work because helpers can't call render more than once, I've also tried defining a function in my view however it doesn't seem to like that either.

I'm wondering if I am approaching this problem the wrong way.

What is the correct way to using recursive functions so that I can render a tree structure in my rails view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this is the clearest way to recursively render components in Rails:

Inside the partial `_comment.html.erb`

```
<%= comment.data %>
<% comment.children.each do |child| %>
  <ul class="child-thread">
    <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: child } %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Your `Comment` model should have this method:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :parent, :foreign_key => :parent_id
  def children 
    Comment.where(parent_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

So, a comment has a `parent_id` which is either NULL (in the case of a root-level comment) or it is another `comment.id`. You can easily set a hard lock on the level of recursion by passing a local variable down the line:

```
<%= comment.data %>
<% if count < 5 %>
  <% comment.children.each do |child| %>
    <ul class="child-thread">
      <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', 
          locals: { comment: child, count: count + 1 } %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This solution has a similar problem to marks as it only deals with one level of depth. It won’t render the children of children and the children of children of children etc

Comment: That's simply not true. Each partial renders a new partial for each of it's children. I'm using this code in production right now. It's pretty simple. It's a recursive solution. The`_comment.html.erb` partial will render **itself** as long as there are children comments. It doesn't stop after one render. It continues to render **itself** recursively until it reaches the maximum depth or stack overflow. Hence why I offered the solution to hard-code a limit. I double checked my code right now. It's 100% working. So, I don't know what you're talking about @Jamesla.

Comment: While you are on the right track your `children` method is just a plain bad idea. Create an association instead so that you can join the children and avoid a n+1 query.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you there. Though my solution works, it's causing an N+1 query. But for my own hobby project? Yeah, it was an easy quick solution. I just wanted to be clear, my solution is a valid Rails solution for producing the intended result, but I have been reminded from this thread about the N+1 issue that my solution doesn't address. So, thank you for clarifying for posterity's sake as future people might use mine erroneously. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: You're right sorry I didn't understand it upon first glance. This works great!

Answer (score 1):

Helper can render more than once, but it has to combine resulting strings and return only one:

```rb
def render_children(id)
  children = Comment.where(parent_id: id).to_a
  safe_join(
    children.map{|comment|
      safe_join([
        render(partial: "comment", locals: { comment: comment }),
        render_children(comment.id)
      ])
    }
  )
end
```

Running separate query per each comment will produce too much load for large threads.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a glowing example of a [N+1 query](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html) which will kill the performance of your application. Each iteration calls `Comment.where(parent_id: id)` which creates an additional database query.

You should start by setting up proper associations so that you can just call `#children` on a comment instance to get nested comments instead of doing `Comment.where(parent_id: id)`:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

This will let you use `.includes` or `.eager_load` to fetch the children in the same query:

```
<% render partial: 'comment', collection: Comment.where(parent_id: nil).includes(:children) %>
```

However this will only work one level deep. Rails does not really support recursive association loading but you can fake it:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :parent_id

  def self.deep_includes(levels = 5)
    hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)  }
    keys = Array.new(levels, :children)
    keys.inject(hash) {|h, k| h[k] }[:children] = :children  
    self.includes(hash)
  end
end
```

This really just does:

```
Comment.includes({:children=>{:children=>{:children=>{:children=>{:children=>{:children=>:children}}}}}})
```

Which produces a whopping SQL query which joins each level.

```
<% render partial: 'comment', collection: Comment.where(parent_id: nil).deep_includes %>
```

With that taken care of making a recursive partial is actually much easier than you think:

```
# app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
<div class="comment">
   <p><%= comment.data %></p>
   <% if comment.children.any? %>
   <div class="children">
     <%= render partial: "comment", collection: comment.children %>
   </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

You don't really need a helper method and an extra level of complexity.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the best way to handle this is to iterate through your children collection, and render a partial for each one in your view:

```
<% comments.where(parent_id: nil).each do |parent| %>
  <!-- render root node -->
  <%= render partial: "comment", locals: { comment: parent } %>
  <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
    <%= render partial: "comment", locals: { comment: child } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Please note this assumes your parent object has many `children` (replace with whatever relationship is relevant if that's not the case) and that you want to render the same partial called `comment` for both the parent and the children.

Comment: This solution would only work if there were 2 levels of depth (parent and child), however as mentioned above there is unlimited number of depth.

IE somebody can post a comment and somebody can reply to that comment, someone can reply to that comment, someone can reply to that comment etc etc

(via self referencing id's on the comment)

Comment: Can you not just make a collection of children in the helper method and use that to iterate through as I did?

Comment: No because you need to render the children of the children and then the children of those children etc so since you don’t know how many levels of depth there will be it needs to be done dynamically